# Gulp: How to change modification time of file

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have gulp task below and with every run of this task (before browsersync) I want to change last modification time of one file (nothing changes in that file, I just need to change time of last modification - alternative to shell "touch" command). Can somebody tell me what's the easiest way to do that please? Thanks!

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {

    return sass(pkg.sass.dir, {sourcemap: true, precision: 10}) 
        .on('error', function (err) { 
            onError(err);
        })
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'],
            cascade: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.css.dir))
        .pipe(browsersync.reload({stream:true}));
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the core `fs` module's [fs.utimes](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#fs_fs_utimes_path_atime_mtime_callback) function, which is the node analog to the Unix `touch` command. You pass the path and if you pass a `new Date()` as the `mtime` parameter, that should do the trick.

Comment: Any hints on how to pull this off in a `pipe()`?

Comment: @WraithKenny I'd suggest opening an issue on the gulp-touch-cmd github repository asking for an update to support gulp v4. Seems like that project was a one-and-done effort 2 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

`gulp-touch-cmd` and `gulp-touch` don't seem to work as of Gulp 4, so I wrote this little pipe function that works. (`npm add through2`)

```js
const through2 = require( 'through2' );    

// example
    .pipe( through2.obj( function( file, enc, cb ) {
        let date = new Date();
        file.stat.atime = date;
        file.stat.mtime = date;
        cb( null, file );
    }) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( '.' ) )
```

Edit: A better, reusable example

```js
...
const through2 = require( 'through2' );    

const touch = () => through2.obj( function( file, enc, cb ) {
    if ( file.stat ) {
        file.stat.atime = file.stat.mtime = file.stat.ctime = new Date();
    }
    cb( null, file );
});

...

gulp.task( 'sass', function() {
    return gulp.src( pkg.sass.dir )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe( sass() )
        .pipe( postcss() )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write() )
        .pipe( touch() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( pkg.css.dir ) );
});
```

Comment: The advantage here is it lets gulp itself set the correct times when it writes to the file, instead of a manual touch after the fact.

Comment: This solution also fixed my issue with PHPStorm after switching to Gulp 4.x.  PHPStorm would not show any updates to files altered by Gulp tasks.  Once this code was added to the Gulp tasks, PHPStorm has been showing the updated files correctly.

Comment: Why can `file.stat` or `file` sometimes be `undefined`?  I had to wrap in an `if`. Works fine othewise

Answer (score 6):

The Gulp plugin [gulp-touch-fd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-touch-fd) fix the Gulp 4 compatibility issue of [gulp-touch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-touch)

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-touch-fd@funkedigital/gulp-touch-fd
```

Example:

```
const {src, dest} = require('gulp');
const touch = require('gulp-touch-fd');

function copyAndTouch() {
  return src('./src/**/*')
    .pipe(dest('./dest'))
    .pipe(touch());
};

exports.copyAndTouch = copyAndTouch
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Using this with Foundation I only needed the `gul-touch-fd` plugin and `const touch = require('gulp-touch-fd');'. I then added it to the `sass` function just before `.pipe(browser.reload({ stream: true }));`

Answer (score 3):

simply you can use [gulp-touch-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-touch-cmd)

Change file access and modification times of files copied using gulp

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-touch-cmd

var gulp = require('gulp');
var touch = require('gulp-touch-cmd');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp
    .src('./src/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'))
    .pipe(touch());
});
```

Comment: don't like that this is using the default task, but moving .pipe(touch()) to whichever file I want is working!

Comment: task "default" is only for demo :)

Answer (score 1):

If we only need the date set to "now", [`gulp-touch-fd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-touch-fd) works, but not if we need to set the modification time to something more specific (like `touch -t` or `touch -r`).

For that we can use [`gulp-touch-custom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-touch-custom):

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const touch = require('gulp-touch-custom');
const through = require('through2');
const Vinyl = require('vinyl');

function exampleproc() {
  return through.obj(function (file, encoding, cb) {
    // example: push a new output file that is timestamped to match its input
    this.push(new Vinyl({
      path: `${file.relative}.out`,
      contents: file.contents.reverse(),
      touch: file.stat.mtime, // Specify an optional Date to use here (copy from input file)
    }));
    // example: Set an explicit date
    file.touch = new Date('2000-01-01');
    cb(null, file);
  });
}

gulp.task('example', function () {
  return gulp.src('./**/*.in')
    .pipe(exampleproc())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'))
    .pipe(touch());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fs.writeFileSync('sporks','','utf8','a')